# How to drag a view from outside scrollview and put it on the scrollview when the scrollview is zoomed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to drag a uiview from main view and just want to put it on the uiscrollview. if the scrollview is not zoomed it is working perfectly but once it zoomed the placement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When your `scrollView` is zoomed, you can anyway consider the `scale factor` and resize the frame of the `UIView` dragged.

Comment: i have already done that stuff and i am still unable to put at the desired position